# page.VisualEffect in rails 3 with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to migrate to rails 3 and UJS with jquery

Now my old code is like this:

```
page['contact_detail_data'].visual_effect :scrollTo,:duration => 0.5,:offset => -30
```

Now in jquery I think I must use animate

so I thought of :

```
page['contact_detail_data'].animate :scrollTo,:duration => 0.5,:offset => -30
```

But I am unsure of how to give parameters can someone please guide me ?

Comment: have you read jQuery documentation?

Comment: @ariel the point is I don no how to pass parameters using ROR . so how would jquery documentation help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this :

```
page.call("anim_up_down","certification_#{params[:index]}",30,500 )
```

And in javascript

```
function anim_up_down(ele,extraoffset,duration){

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+ele).offset().top-extraoffset},duration)

}
```

Comment: now Jrails support visual effect.
Try using jrails new version